# How to fix zsh: command not found: process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

[image]what i am trying to set 'NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED’ as 0 by running the command ; export `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` in terminal (MAC) , getting the error as

zsh: command not found: process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

use like this it is working on mac

> export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).